# Is an Experience Certificate valid without bank statements showing salary credit?

Tags: job-change, work-experience, india

My previous company paid my salary by [NEFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Electronic_Funds_Transfer) to my bank account, and also gave me salary slips. When the company shut down, they gave me an Experience Certificate confirming my work there.

Now I work for another company, which is a startup. They do not pay the salary by NEFT, but rather give me cash each month. Hence, there is no salary credit  in my bank account.

When applying for jobs in future, is the Experience Certificate from this company sufficient to confirm that I was employed here? Do companies usually ask for bank statements as well to verify employment?

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan I think what OP meant is, "Is my Experience Certificate valid if I receive salary as cash (as against an electronic transfer to bank account)?" I work in India too, so I could make some sense of it, but I agree it is very incoherent. I had to read it 4 times to figure out (and I am still not certain if I understood it right). :-)

Comment: @myname If my above comment is the correct interpretation of your problem, please confirm, I will make an edit for you.

Comment: By the way, what do you mean by "agreement basic"? Never heard of this term during my 7 years of working in India.

Comment: I have not come across any company which asks for "bank statements". They ask for salary slips from previous company, but it is none of their business looking into your bank account. Also, if you are working in a non-registered company, I doubt your experience would be counted even if they give you an experience letter. After all, I too could give you salary slips and "experience letter" saying you worked for my (non-existent) McAwesomeCool Corporation.

Comment: @myname hey, i massively edited your question, i think i captured the gist of what you wanted to ask.

Comment: @myname i can edit the question, but i don't have any insights on indian work issues to give you any sort of answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the company is registered with the [Registrar of Companies](http://www.mca.gov.in/MinistryV2/registrarofcompanies.html), then an Experience Letter on the company's official letterhead would be valid. You can use the [Ministry of Corporate Affairs website](http://www.mca.gov.in/mcafoportal/checkCompanyName.do) to check the company's registration status.

If the company shuts down in future, your future employers would find it difficult to verify your experience. In that case, you should use the [Right to Information Act](http://rti.gov.in/) to request the Ministry of Corporate Affairs for a statement showing the time period through which the company was registered. Their response along with your Experience Letter should be sufficient proof of work experience.

The mode of salary payment is not relevant to the validity of Experience Letter. However, if you are receiving salary by cash, it is in your best interest to obtain a salary slip. You could otherwise run into problems when you apply for a new job.

Comment: I don't work in India, but my experience tells me that being paid in cash is almost always bad. Any company doing this is on shaky ground. If they are treating you badly, tryong to escape legally required expenses, I can guarantee they will expect you to do illegal/immoral things and they may try to sabotage you from leaving. You may not get unemployment if the company goes under, your taxes are not properly taken out. Other things such as retirement, health care, workman's comp or their equivalent in your country are probably also not being taken out.

Comment: @HLGEM It is not uncommon in India for small companies to pay employees by cash. The employee signs a "cash receipt", and gets a copy of it, which is usually good enough for all legal purposes. There are other laws and procedures in place to ensure that the cash payments are accounted for wrt taxes and stuff. This is the result of financial inclusion in India being rather low for an economy of its size. India's recently elected new Prime Minister is quite keen on fixing this. See: [Pradhan Mantri Jan Dhan Yojana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pradhan_Mantri_Jan_Dhan_Yojana).

Comment: That said, however, in the OP's case here, the second company sounds rather shady based on the other points mentioned, such as not signing any kind of contract with the OP (he subsequently deleted that comment from below the question).

Comment: From seeing some of the problems people who are paid in cash have getting visas, if you might want to travel internationally deposit the cash into your bank account and use the money from there. Ideally, you will have matching payslips and deposits. See [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/66104/19560) for what some immigration officers are looking for in bank account statements.